# I want to hide URL parameters of my website page by using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

> http://eoflex/CAportal/readmore/?slug=blogtitle

I am trying to hide url parameters by .htaccess file is it possible to show url like this ?

- http://eoflex/CAportal/blogtitle

Give me solution I am new to .htaccess file 
I am writing code in .htaccess file  given below and its not working, i want url like http://eoflex/CAportal/blogtitle I don't want to display /?slug=blogtitle*

```
 RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ page.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Set rewrite rule based on your url and the path of your htaccess file. if your htaccess file is into readmore directory, it should work.

Comment: Why do you have `page.php` in your rewrite rule?

Answer (score 4):

you can use the following Code in .htaccess file . you can also use apache rewrite module . By First enabling apache rewrite module in apache server .

**Write Below Lines In .htaccess file**

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/CAportal/readmore/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /CAportal/readmore/page.php?slug=$1

**HINT**

^/read/This/Url/blogtitle /as/This/Url/page.php?slug=blogtitle

**INFO**

^
Matches the beginning of a string

$
Matches the end of a string

[0-9]
Matches a number, 0–9. [2-4] would match numbers 2 to 4 inclusive.

[a-z]
Matches lowercase letters a–z

[A-Z]
Matches uppercase letters A–Z

[a-z0-9]
Combining some of these, this matches letters a–z and numbers 0–9

Comment: The `^` anchor in front of the regex breaks the rule, and it may be desirable to put a ? after the trailing slash so it's optional, but otherwise this looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (put this in .htaccess in the document root).

```
RewriteRule ^CAportal/readmore/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /CAPortal/readmore/?slug=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but your code is not working @drew010

Comment: Rewrite rules are case-sensitive.  I did not notice the "p" in portal was lowercase.  I updated the answer so it should work now. @HirenPatel